# PairedBarChart: Remove space at bottom and add tick axes

Tags: ticks, charts

I have two questions about adapting a PairedBarChart to my needs.

1.I have a PairedBarChart with many bars like this

```
   size = 50;
        PairedBarChart[RandomReal[1, size], RandomReal[1, size], 
         AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I changed the AspectRatio (e.g. 3 in this case but could be higher)

```
size = 50;
PairedBarChart[RandomReal[1, size], RandomReal[1, size], 
 AspectRatio -> 3]
```

Now there is a space at the bottom between the axis and the last bar which gets larger the higher the Aspect Ratio.

How can I remove that space at the bottom or make it a specific length respectively?

2.I want to add another axis on the top of the Chart with ticks of my choice, i.e. not from 0 to 1 but another scale e.g. 0 to 100. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Your first question can be solved with the following:  `PairedBarChart[RandomReal[1, size], RandomReal[1, size], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, size}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}]`.  To see that `ImagePadding` is necessary, try it without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code that answers both of the questions:

```
size = 50;
PairedBarChart[RandomReal[1, size], RandomReal[1, size], 
 AspectRatio -> 2, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, 
    None}, {{#, 100 #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.25], {#, 100 #} & /@ 
     Range[0, 1, 0.25]}}]
```

[image]

Answering a comment by @user6014 :

> I took his post to mean he wanted the original ticks on the bottom,
>   but an alternative one on top. Yours merely replaces both the top and
>   the bottom. Is what I interpreted possible, i.e. 2 different ticks
>   sets? (perhaps I misinterpreted the poster, though...)

```
size = 50;
PairedBarChart[RandomReal[1, size], RandomReal[1, size], 
 AspectRatio -> 2, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, 
    None}, {Range[0, 1, 0.25], {#, 100 #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.25]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I took his post to mean he wanted the original ticks on the bottom, but an alternative one on top. Yours merely replaces both the top and the bottom. Is what I interpreted possible, i.e. 2 different ticks sets? (perhaps I misinterpreted the poster, though...)

Comment: @user6014 I think you are probably right, and that is easily done with the option value of `FrameTicks`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @AntonAntonov: Thanks very much! I wanted to display two different ticks which you already answered as well, great :)